# Calculating the parent of a relative file

Tags: file, uri

So assuming a relative URI

```
../file.ext
```

Would the parent be

```
../
```

or

```
../../file.ext
```

If its the first, then what's the parent of

```
../
```

and it's the second, what would terminate a potentially infinite cycle if one were to repeatedly call a hypothetical getParent method upon it?

Comment: I'm confused. An a recursive call to getParent() should stop when the string is either empty or when there are no more "/" in it... if I understand you correctly, but I'm afraid I'm a bit confused as to what exactly your question is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a "current directory" of

```
/you/are/here/
```

then `../file.ext` will be

```
/you/are/file.ext
```

and `../../file.ext` will be

```
/you/file.ext
```

Given a `getParent()` function, it'd have to stop when it reaches the top level of the filesystem. That's trivial to check for by looking at the inode numbers of `.` and `..`. If they match, you're at the top of the tree. By definition, doing '..' at the top of the tree will just return the top of the tree again.

Comment: Thanks Marc! I wasn't sure about .. at top of the tree.

Comment: Bonus points- could you tell me if it is appropriate for the parent of a URI composed of an empty string (which is a valid URI reference apparently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) to resolve to '/'? This is a purely syntactic question btw

Comment: Very old versions of Apache had the problem where you could specify enough "../../.." in a URL and break out of the webroot and start moving around the filesystem. But that was locked down long ago. Now, once you reach the webroot, doing '../' becomes a null op and Apache treats the top of the webroot the same as the top of the filesystem. There's nothing wrong with `example.com/?a=b`, it'll just use the default document (index.html/index.php, etc...) located in the webroot.